# EXC_BAD_ACCESS - NSFetchedResultsController, UITableViewController, UINavigationController, UIPopoverController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, automatic-ref-counting

I have a `UITableViewController` inside a `UINavigationController`, inside a `UIPopoverController`.

The `UITableViewController` uses a `NSFetchedResultsController`. *didSelectRowAtIndexPath* pushes another instance of my `UITableViewController` with a *slightly different* predicate onto the nav controller stack.

If I push a new `UITableViewController` on to the stack, and then pop it again, I will eventually get a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` if I try to save an object that would have updated the tableview that was popped off.

As expected, setting the delegate of my `NSFetchedResultsController` to `nil` removes the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` errors.

I am using ARC. So clearly these objects are getting released. This is OK. But why are they still getting notified when there is a change?

Code below. I am basically tracking the history of a web view in my database.

```
BookmarkViewController * bookmarkController = [[BookmarkViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain andWebView:self.webView];
UINavigationController * bookmarkNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:bookmarkController];
self.bookmarkPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:bookmarkNavController];
_bookmarkPopover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 44*10);
_bookmarkPopover.delegate = self;
bookmarkController.container=_bookmarkPopover;
bookmarkController.delegate=self;
```

The `BookmarkViewController` uses an `NSFetchedResultsController` and `BookmarkViewController` is the `delegate` of the `NSFetchedResultsController`.

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *) myFetchedResultsController
{   
    if (self.fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return self.fetchedResultsController;
    }   
    // Singleton
    CoreDataManager * dataManager = [CoreDataManager defaultDataManager];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Bookmark" inManagedObjectContext:dataManager.managedObjectContext];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"label" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:self.predicate];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors]; 
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20]; // Set the batch size to a suitable number.

    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                    managedObjectContext:dataManager.managedObjectContext
                                                                      sectionNameKeyPath:@"type"
                                                                               cacheName:nil];
    self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return self.fetchedResultsController;
}
```

And also I have:

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {    
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    BookmarkViewController * bookmarkViewController = [[BookmarkViewController alloc] initWithStyle:self.tableView.style 
                                                                                         andWebView:self.webview 
                                                                                          forFolder:bookmark.label];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:bookmarkViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some related questions:

[Deallocated view controller causing EXC_BAD_ACCESS because of fetched results controller update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025763/deallocated-view-controller-causing-exe-bad-access-because-of-fetched-results-co)

[If I release, I get bad access, if I retain, I leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006028/if-i-release-i-get-bad-access-if-i-retain-i-leak)

The 2nd link gave me the idea of setting the delegate to nil in the dealloc method

```
-(void) dealloc
{
    self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = nil;
}
```

But I am using ARC so I cannot call `[super dealloc]` explicitly. Appears to fix the problem, but I am not sure this is correct. Should I also set the rest of my local variables to `nil`? If this overrides what ever the compiler generates, will it leak?

Comment: You can't call `[super dealloc]` explicitly, because you no longer need to. This is all handled for you. You don't need to nil out your remaining properties, but you can use `-dealloc` to clean up any observers you've set up with this object.