# How to manage unsafe_unretained ivars/properties?

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting, unsafe-unretained

I started objective-c and iOS a couple of weeks ago (worth bearing in mind), and I apologise in advance for the awful diagram!!

[image]

The above diagram shows the structure of my calls to a webservice.  Thin arrows denote an object creating another object, whereas thick arrows denote an object holding a strong (retained) reference to the pointed-to object.

I believe that this contains what is called a "circular reference" and will create problems when it comes to deallocating the objects.

I understand that the easy answer would be to replace some of the strong references to weak ones, which I'd love to do, except my project is also targeting iOS 3.2 (not my decision - I can't really change this fact!).  So, I think I'm right in saying that I have to use __unsafe_unretained instead, but I'm quite worried about the fact that these won't auto-zero, as I'll end up with EXC_BAD_ACCESS problems when objects get deallocated...

So my problem is firstly that I have circular references.  To solve, I would have to use __unsafe_unretained, which leads to my second problem: How to correctly manage these?

A question that might be related is: How does NSURLConnection manage it's strong references?  I have heard from various sources that it retains its delegate?  So...if I retain an NSURLConnection, (and am also its delegate) and it retains me, this would also be a circular reference, no?  How does it get around my problem?

Any advice is very welcome!

Regards,
Nick

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a parent has a reference to a child object, it should use a strong reference. When a child has a reference to it's parent object, it should use a weak reference, aka unsafe_unretained.

By convention, delegate relationships in iOS are usually weak references, so you'll find that most delegate properties on Apple's own classes are declared as unsafe_unretained.

So your controller retains the services that it is using, but the services only weakly link back to the controller. That way, if the controller is released, the whole lot can be safely disposed of without any circular references.

The danger with this is that if the web service is doing some long-running task, and the controller gets released before it has finished, the service is left with a dangling pointer to it's now-deallocated delegate. If it tries to send a message to the delegate, such as "I have finished" it will crash.

There are a few approaches to help solve this (they aren't mutually exclusive - you should try to do them all whenever possible):

1) Always set the delegate properties of your services to nil in your controller's dealloc method. This ensures that when the controller is released, the delegate references to it are set to nil (sort of a crude, manual equivalent of what ARC's weak references do automatically).

2) When creating your own service classes that have delegates, make them retain their delegate while they are running and then release the delegate when they are done. That way the delegate object can't get deallocated while the service is still sending it messages, but it will still get released once the service has finished (NSTimer's and NSURLConnections both work this way - they retain their delegate while they are running and release it when they are done).

3) Try not to have long-running services owned by something transient like a view controller. Consider creating singleton objects (shared static object instances) that own your services, that way the service can do it's job in the background regardless of what's going on in the view layer. The controller can still call the service, but doesn't own it - the service is owned by a static object that will exist for the duration that the app is running, and so there's no risk of leaks or premature releases. The service can communicate with the controller via NSNotifications instead of delegate calls, so there is no need for it to have a reference to an object that may vanish. NSNotifications are a great way to communicate between multiple classes without creating circular references.

Comment: Wow, great response, thanks! I have a basic understanding of the whole child-parent relationship with regards to strong and weak references, but I'm not sure if my understanding is flawed, because (in my example) if I were to make the references to both ServiceResponse and SpecificResponseHandler weak ones, then the objects would never be retained, and therefore would be deallocated almost immediately.  So in my example, that is why I have strong references to those objects.  With this in mind, does you think it reasonable to keep the strong references in those cases only?

Comment: I would say that specific service is the parent of specific response handler and service request owns service response, so those should be strong references, but I may have misunderstood your diagram. If those are long lived objects, maybe they should all just be owned by a "sharedServiceModel" singleton, and then all the interconnections can be weak,

Comment: If it helps a child should never be the delegate of it's parent. If you've got that going on, you may want to rethink your architecture. It looks a little bit like some of those delegate relationships are ownership relationships, but that doesn't make sense. If I want to send messages to an object that I own, that's not a delegate, it's just a property. Delegate objects should own the object delegating to them - like a view controller owns a button, and the button delegates it's click to the controller that owns it, not the other way around.

Comment: Ah ok, this seems to be turning into an architectural problem.  I understand what you're saying with regards to an object not being a delegate if it owns it.  With that in mind, I think the most sensible thing is to have the ServiceRequest be the parent/owner of both the Service Response and SpecificResponseHandler, which will allow me to turn the delegate relationships into weak ones.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

All of your questions and concerns are correct, and this problem with the previous use of `assign` (now better named `__unsafe_unretained`) is why Apple developed auto-zeroing for `weak`. But we've dealt reasonably safely with `assign` delegates for many years, so as you suspect, there are ways to do it.

First, as a matter of practice, you should always clear yourself as the delegate when your release an object you were delegate for. Pre-ARC, this was traditionally done in `dealloc`:

```
- (void)dealloc {
  [tableView_ setDelegate:nil];
  [tableView_ release];
  tableView_ = nil;
}
```

You should still include that `setDelegate:nil` in your `dealloc` if `delegate` is `__unsafe_unretained`. This will address the most common form of the problem (when the delegate is deallocated before the delegating object).

Regarding `NSURLConnection`, you are also correct that it retains its delegate. This is ok because it has a lifespan typically much shorter than its delegate (versus a table view delegate which almost always has the same lifespan as the table view). See " [How to work around/handle delegation EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors? Obj C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672803/how-to-work-around-handle-delegation-exc-bad-access-errors-obj-c) " for more discussion on this in a pre-ARC context (the same concepts apply in the new world of strong/weak).

Comment: Very helpful, thanks! I was unsure what the use of dealloc methods was with ARC enabled (the only book I have is on iOS4, rather unhelpfully!), but clearly I hadn't considered this use of it.