# iOS App crashing on production but not on debugging

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode4.6, crash-log

I have been working on an iOS app. It was working fine until a couple of days ago, it started behaving strangely. The app crashes on production but it creates no crash logs. However, when same scenario is tested out in QA, it works fine. Now I have been trying to find out the reason but without any crash logs or crash in debugging mode, it has become very difficult for me.

Any suggestion, how to tackle it?

Thanks!

P.S. I am using XCode 4.6.1 and app is for iOS 6.0.

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall the app and re-installed it?

Comment: Yes, been doing everything both sane and insane!

Comment: try to check the behavior .. if you will modify your release (Target \ Build Settings \ Optimization Lavel \ Release) to None (from Fastest, Smallest..)..

Comment: Been there, done that!

Comment: is working well with None?

Comment: TonyMkenu, you helped me, but in "Swift Compiler - Code Generation"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, I have found out after detailed research on the internet that some crashes kill the application before logging the `Crash Log`. My error was that of a delegate property for my services. After long hard tries, I got to the root cause of the problem, since I had converted the code to ARC so the delegate property was `unsafe_unreatained`, which released the delegate while it was still in use by the service, so I just had to convert it into strong and set it to nil in `dealloc`. Further description can be seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9065105/1351911.

Comment: This is all good, but you don’t need to set it to nil the dealloc. ARC will do that for you for strongly held variables.

Comment: @DanRosenstark That was 2013, I was a bigger idiot back then :D

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, building ipa's in Xcode 4.6.1 with sdk version 6.0 or above crashes the app like anything. Try archiving it in Xcode 4.4 or 4.3 may be a lower version and try.

Comment: I have one 4.5.2. I'll try from there and let you know. Also, have you come across the reason why is it occuring?

Comment: It's like my XCode has forgotten to log crashes anymore!